How keep Active Choices Reactive selections persisting Jenkins
I was wondering how best to keep Active Choices Reactive selections persisting when the reference parameter changes in Jenkins.
It seems like everytime you change to another Active Choices parameter, the previous selections from the Active Choice Reactive parameter list are no longer highlighted when you return to the same Active Choices parameter.
